# Android list view onItemClick on Enter Key press

Tags: android, listview

I have a list view where we have several items to be selected by user.

When ENTER key is pushed the call is going into onItemCLick()

How can I stop this behaviour ?

I want that the call should go into this method only when
user touches a list view item.

Comment: ENTER means which key ?? I never see ENTER key as hardware in Android Device. Are you talking about SoftKey of keyboard?

Comment: if you ARE talking about the SoftKeyboard, there's a listener designed for that (onEditorAction)

Comment: Yes I am talking about SOftKeyBoard.

Comment: can you show image of your softkeyboard with listview

Comment: Sorry that won't be possible. It's kind of confidential

Comment: @Ankit I cant believe that this possible thats why I am asking. Sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

Try to hide the SoftKeyboard when the listview shows. I believe that you're testing your app on the emulator. When you test your app on the actual mobile you will not see the Enter key.

Answer (score -3):

```
public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            // If the event is a key-down event on the "enter" button
            if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                    && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                // Perform action on key press
                // Editable a=findViewById(R.id.username).getText();
                // username2.setText(a);

                Toast.makeText(yassou.this, username2.getText(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Just for your kind information always try to give full answer, otherwise you will got lots of downvotes